# Solution of a symbolic logic problem with Separation of Cases inference rule

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$$(( S \land \lnot P ) \lor ( Q \land R )) ∴ ( \lnot P \lor Q )$$

I am trying to solve this symbolic logic problem ^^ with the separation of cases inferences rule but I am having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) $( S \land \lnot P ) \lor ( Q \land R )$ --- premise

2) $( S \land \lnot P )$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot P$ --- from 2) by [Conjunction elimination](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formal_Logic/Sentential_Logic/Inference_Rules) (or *simplification*)

4) $(\lnot P \lor Q)$ --- from 3) by *Disjunction introduction*

5)  $( S \land \lnot P ) \rightarrow (\lnot P \lor Q)$ --- from 2) and 4) by *Conditional introduction*, discharging [a]

6) $( Q \land R )$ --- assumed [b]

7) $Q$ --- from 6) by *Conjunction elimination*

8) $(\lnot P \lor Q)$ --- from 7) by *Disjunction introduction*

9) $( Q \land R ) \rightarrow (\lnot P \lor Q)$ --- from 6) and 8) by *Conditional introduction*, discharging [b]

> > 7) $(\lnot P \lor Q)$ --- from 1), 5) and 9) by [Disjunction elimination](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formal_Logic/Sentential_Logic/Inference_Rules) (or *Separation of Cases*).